# Persistent class variables

Tags: c++, static, initialization

I have a question regarding static variables, or some other way to do so.

I have a master class, PatternMatcher. I have several derived units from that, depending on what matcher is used. Now each subclass needs to store a vector of floats, but within each class it is constant. The data for that vector is read during initialization, and can be up to 1GB in size (smallest I have is 1MB, biggest is 1GB). 
Currently when I have for example two instances of Matcher_A, it would allocate twice the memory. I do not know in advance which matchers are to be used (per run it will be three matchers, and you can use the same matcher several times). I would prefer to not check during run time whether the wanted matcher is already initialized somewhere, since this would require additional code for every change I do.

Currently I allocate the 3 matchers with

```
PatternMatcher* a = new PMMatcherA();
PatternMatcher* b = new PMMatcherB();
PatternMatcher* c = new PMMatcherC();
```

, but since they are user selected, it could happen that A and C are the same for example. When I run a check via `typeid(a).name();`, it would give me PatternMatcher as result, never matter what class I used to initiate with. PatternMatcher basically is purely a virtual class.

I always thought that static means that a variable is constant over different allocations, but when I define my vector as static, I would get a linker resolve error. In an earlier iteration, I had these vectors global, but would prefer them to be localized to their classes.

What are the keywords I need to use to have the vector from on initialization be available for the next initialization already? A simple check if the vector size is greater than 0 would already be enough, but every object uses its own vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` keyword **is** a way to go - that would store exactly one copy of a member for the whole class. What you were missing is an actual declaration of such static in a compilation module so that the linker can use it. For instance:

`header file foo.h`:

```
struct Foo {
  static int s_int;
}
```

`source file foo.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.h"
int Foo::s_int; // optionally =0 for initialization
```

The second part is vital as this will allocate a memory space for the object to be used as a static member.

Keep in mind, though, that:

- `static` members will **all** be initialized *before* the `main()`, which means your 1GB of data will be read regardless of whether anyone ever uses that particular class
- You can work around the abovementioned issue, but then you will have to be checking if the data load and initialization has happened during run-time

There's another option for you, however. If you store your floats "as-is" (i.e. 32 bits per each, in binary format) you can just simply "map" the files into memory spaces and access them as if they were already loaded - the OS will take care of loading appropriate 4K pages into RAM when needed.

Read more about `mmap` at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap

Comment: Thanks, that did it. The vector itself gets stacked with data only after the matcher is called the very first time, so initially each will be only sizeof(vector), which is perfectly fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `static` is what you need. You can use it like this:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    static std::vector< float > data_;
};

std::vector< float > MyClass::data_;
```

Please note that in the class itself you only *declare* static variables. But you also need to *define* them outside of the class *exactly once*. That's why we have the line `std::vector< float > MyClass::data_;`, if you omit that, you will have linker errors.

After this, *every* object of `MyClass` class will share the same `data_` vector.

You can operate it either from any object of the class:

```
MyClass a;
a.data_.push_back(0);
```

or through the class name:

`MyClass::data_.push_back(0);`

Answer (score 1):

> when I define my vector as static, I would get a linker resolve
>   error.

This is because you declare the static variable (in your header file) but you never explicitly initialize it in one of your implementation file (.cpp).

For example:

```
//AClass.h 
class AClass
{
    private:
    static std::vector<int> static_vector;

};
```

and in the .cpp implementation file:

```
std::vector<int> AClass::static_vector;
```